# Python unicode issue with subprocess.call

Tags: python, unicode, subprocess, python-unicode

My parser function uses `lxml` and provides me a list of unicode strings (`book_list`).

The strings are joined together into a file name, cleaned up and then passed via `subprocess.call` to another binary which continues the work.

My problem is that the unicode objects (e.g. `title_name = u'Wunderlicher Traum von einem gro\xdfen Narrennest'`) are encoded in ISO-8859-2 (at least that's what 'chardet' tells me) and I need to convert them to a format, which gets properly displayed on file system level. The current code results the file name to be `u'Wunderlicher Traum von einem gro\xc3\x9fen Narrennest'`.

Does anyone have an idea what I'm doing wrong?

Some infos:

- `sys.getdefaultencoding()` returns `ascii`, which confuses me, since that theoretically shouldn't allow any special characters like äöü etc.).
- OS X 10.9, Python 2.7.5

---

```
def convert_books(book_list, output_dir):
    for book in book_list:
        author_name = book[0][0]
        title_name = book[0][1]
        #print chardet.detect(title_name)
        #print type(title_name)
        #print title_name.decode('iso-8859-2')
        year_name = "1337"

        output_file = u"%s - %s (%s).pdf" % (author_name, title_name, year_name)
        keep_characters = (' ', '.', '_')
        output_file.join(c for c in output_file if c.isalnum() or c in keep_characters).rstrip()
        path_to_out = "%s%s" % (output_dir, output_file)

        target_file = WORK_DIR + book[1].replace(".xml", ".html")

        engine_parameter = [
            WKHTMLTOPDF_BIN,

            # GENERAL
            "-l", # lower quality
            "-L", "25mm",
            "-R", "25mm",
            "-T", "25mm",
            "-B", "35mm",
            "--user-style-sheet", "media/style.css",

            target_file,
            path_to_out,
        ]
        print "+ Creating PDF \"%s\"" % (output_file)
        call(engine_parameter)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After writing down the question, the cause of the issued to be clear :)

- `\xdf` is UTF-8
- `\xc3\x9f`is ISO-8859-1 or latin-1

All I had to do was convert the utf-8 objects to latin-1 objects and then pass the arguments to subprocess.call.

```
out_enc = 'latin-1'
engine_parameter = [arg.encode(out_enc) if isinstance(arg, unicode) else arg for arg in engine_parameter]
call(engine_parameter)
```

Hope this will save someone else the headache!